# Asynchronously writing ByteBuffers to an InputStream or Channel or similar

Tags: java

I'm asynchronously getting an unknown number of ByteBuffers (they are send via network). Each contains a part of data, they arrive in the correct order. I want to reassemble them and pass the re-united data to a handler. However, they must not be kept in memory until the last one has arrived, because it can be many megabytes.

So my idea is, to pass an `InputStream` to the handler of that data from which the handler can successively read the data and process it on the fly, e.g. write to the disk. Since `InputStream` cannot be written to, I could use a `PipedOutputStream` and connected it to a `PipedInputStream`. There is a lot of copying involved though (the `PipedInputStream` has its own buffer and then reading is done again by copying to an array) so I'm worried about performance.

Is this even a good idea? Should I use a different technology then streams, e.g. channels?

Comment: I *think* all you should need to do is receive each buffer.  If the handler requires you to send it only one buffer, there's no way to not hold the buffer in memory.  So I guess I'm unclear what is being asked.  Of course it would be best to see some code so we could understand the details of what you are asking.

Comment: If "being held in memory" is a known problem, I'd assume the handler is able handle the data as separate buffers.  I'd verify this first and get clarification about holding data in memory if the answer is that the handler requires all data at once.  I think you may be making this more work than it needs to be.

Comment: No holding in memory == appending to a file on disk. Doesn't really matter how you do it

Comment: Not holding in memory can be to append to a file or to send on the network calculate aggregations on the fly etc, there are many possibilities. And it's a hard requirement.
But yeah, maybe passing the chunks is OK. However, is not pretty and means, the handler cannot be a simple function because I have to pass the chunks one by one and each handler has to handly asynchronicity.

Comment: Some code would go a long way towards explaining what is really going on.  That `PipedInputStream` won't make things easy for your handler?

Comment: Sure, a simple stream of bytes is much simpler to handle than a bunch of asynchronously passed in buffers, I'd say.

Comment: [HttpResponse.BodySubscriber](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.BodySubscriber.html) seems to accomplish this using `Flow.Subscriber<List<ByteBuffer>>`.  Do you have to aggregate all of the data before passing it along?

Comment: Have you considered an *output* stream? Your question is most unclear.

Comment: How does an `OutputStream` help? The handler will not be able to read the data from it.

Comment: @VGR, that's a good hint, I like the idea! They also provide some helpful subscriber implementations. We'll go into that direction. If you don't mind, you could put your comment in an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would send the ByteBuffers directly to the receiver.  The receiver can implement `Flow.Subscriber<List<ByteBuffer>>`, just as [HttpResponse.BodySubscriber](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.BodySubscriber.html) implementations do.

That allows your code to create a [SubmissionPublisher](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/SubmissionPublisher.html) (the only Java SE implementation of `Flow.Publisher` that I know of) and add that receiving subscriber to it:

```
    SubmissionPublisher<List<ByteBuffer>> publisher =
        new SubmissionPublisher<>();

    // ...

    Flow.Subscriber<List<ByteBuffer>> handler = /* ... */;
    publisher.subscribe(handler);

    // ...

    while (dataAvailable) {
        List<ByteBuffer> partialData = /* ... */;
        publisher.submit(partialData);
    }
```

SubmissionPublisher has a number of options for how submission threads are created, and how receiver exceptions are handled.

Answer (score -2):

Historically, ByteBuffers and channels where introduced after input/output streams, because the input/output streams were not efficient and could not be refactored easily to make them efficient. A ByteBuffer can avoid copying of data in certain cases, scatter/gather and other cool features.

If performance/efficiency is important, then streams is not a great option, especially if you already have ByteBuffers.

Channels is one approach to use, though you can simply use ByteBuffers directly (e.g. combine input buffer with your buffer), use Flux/Reactor, or invent your own API. I am sure more options are possible.

Another important point is the ability to push-back, when the consumer of your buffer is slower than your input, to tell your source to hold back while your consumer is taking time to process the data. Without it, you can go out of memory in your layer.

Comment: Historically ByteBuffers arose to handle Channel I/O. If you think they can be ‘refactored’ better than input/output streams please demonstrate. It seems to me that it is by far the other way around.

Comment: I think you misread my answer. `The latter` means input/output streams.

Comment: How does this answer the question? It really seems tangentially related.

Comment: What do you mean? I first say that input/output streams are not great for performance, then I offer 3 concrete ways (Channels, ByteBuffers without Channels and Flux/Reacor) plus your own API.